# print matched lines when column 6 or 7 is greater than 90%

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have data in a text file something like below.

```
server         volume               available total   used  percent-used percent-vol-space
--------------- -------------------- --------- ------- ----- ------------ ----------------------
TEMPSERVER      TEMP_root       972.4MB     972.8MB 388KB 5%           5%
TEMPSERVER      TEMPVOL01           2.59TB      5.13TB  2.55TB 54%         10%
TEMPSERVER      TEMPVOL02           2.26TB      4.10TB  1.53TB 50%         10%
TEMPSERVER      TEMPVOL02_Clone     2.26TB      4.10TB 1.57TB 50% 10%
TEMPSERVER      TEMPVOL03           1.79TB      3.88TB  2.10TB 63%         20%
TEMPSERVER      TEMPVOL03_Clone     2.26TB      4.10TB 1.79TB 50% 10%
TEMPSERVER      TEMPVOL04           3.32TB      4.30TB  807.3GB 30%        10%
22 entries were displayed.
```

Now i want to print each line if the value in column 6 OR 7 are greater than 90%. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR > 2 && (0+$6 > 90 || 0+$7 > 90)' <file
```

This would read the data line by line and whenever a line has a number larger than 90 in the 6th or 7th field, it will be printed.  We skip the first two header lines with `NR > 2` and we add zero to the values in column six and seven to force a conversion to a number (the `%` sign in the data will be dropped by this) before testing them against 90.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane 'print if $. <= 2 || grep { $_ > 90. } @F[5,6]' input-data.file
```

The lines are split on whitespace and fields stored in `@F` array indexed from 0.
header (lines 1,2) are unconditionally printed and the rest are selected based on the filter looking for fields 6th and/or 7th comprising atleast 90% usage.